# warning: "integer constant too large for long type" ... but it is a uint64_t?

Tags: android, c, types, android-ndk

I am working on cross-compiling [libbtbb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libbtbb/) to Android, and I am getting a ton of warnings that say:

```
jni/libbtbb/bluetooth_packet.h:67: warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
```

However, when I dig in to the file, this points to the line:

```
static const uint64_t sw_matrix[] = {
    0xfe000002a0d1c014, 0x01000003f0b9201f, 0x008000033ae40edb, 0x004000035fca99b9,
    0x002000036d5dd208, 0x00100001b6aee904, 0x00080000db577482, 0x000400006dabba41,
    0x00020002f46d43f4, 0x000100017a36a1fa, 0x00008000bd1b50fd, 0x000040029c3536aa,
    0x000020014e1a9b55, 0x0000100265b5d37e, 0x0000080132dae9bf, 0x000004025bd5ea0b,
    0x00000203ef526bd1, 0x000001033511ab3c, 0x000000819a88d59e, 0x00000040cd446acf,
    0x00000022a41aabb3, 0x0000001390b5cb0d, 0x0000000b0ae27b52, 0x0000000585713da9};
```

The type is uint64_t, and not "long" ... but it seems to be referring to specifying the constant like *0xfe000002a0d1c014*.  In this case, I'm not sure how else it should be specified, or if I can ignore these warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `ULL` suffix to your 64-bit integer constants or enclose them in the verbose `UINT64_C` macro from `stdint.h`.

```
static const uint64_t sw_matrix[] = {
    0xfe000002a0d1c014ULL, /* etc. */ };
```

or

```
#include <stdint.h>

static const uint64_t sw_matrix[] = {
    UINT64_C(0xfe000002a0d1c014), /* etc. */ };
```

Answer (score 3):

In the 1989/1990 version of the C standard, the type of a hexadecimal integer constant is the first in this list in which its value can be represented:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`

That version of the language had no `long long` or `unsigned long long` type.

The 1999 version of the standard, this list was changed to:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `long long int`
- `unsigned long long int`

It looks like you're using gcc, which by default recognizes C89/C90 with some GNU-specific extensions. My understanding is that it provides types `long long` and `unsigned long long` as an extension, but doesn't change the semantics of integer constants.

If you invoke gcc with the argument `-std=c99`, it will (attempt to) conform to the C99 standard, and the warnings should go away (no need to change your source code).

If you want to modify your source so it compiles without warnings without `-std=c99`, then adding a `ULL` suffix will cause the constants to be of type `unsigned long long`, which is *probably* the same type as `uint64_t`, but it's not guaranteed.  Using the `UINT64_C()` macro ensures they're of the correct type, but it's a bit verbose.